# Show an log n + bn = O(n log n) regardless of a and b

Tags: math, big-o

I need help understanding a Big-O problem.  I get the concept and have done a few practice problems already, but this one has me stumped.

Using the definition of big O, show that `f(n)=anlogn+bn` is `O(nlogn). (a, b > 0)`

I don't know how to find C or N, because if constants A or B change, then C and N have to change as well?  Or am I looking at this the wrong way?

I have a test coming up, and I'd really like to understand this beforehand.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When you're given a statement like this one:

> Prove that an log n + bn = O(n log n)

You can think of it as the following:

> For any choice of a and b, prove that an log n + bn = O(n log n)

Which in turn means

> For any choice of a and b, there is some choice of c and n<sub>0</sub> such that an log n + bn ≤ cn log n for any n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>.

In other words, you *first* pick a and b, *then* show that an log n + bn = O(n log n).  You're not trying to show that there are a fixed c and n<sub>0</sub> that work in the definition of big-O notation regardless of a and b, but rather should show that no matter how someone picks a and b, you'll always be able to find a c and n<sub>0</sub> - which probably depend on a and b - such that an log n + bn = O(n log n) using those choices of c and n<sub>0</sub>.

To see how you'd do this in this example, one observation that might be useful is that (assuming our logs are base two), 1 ≤ log n as long as n ≥ 2.  Therefore, as long as we restrict n such that n ≥ 2, we get that

> an log n + bn ≤ an log n + bn log n = (a + b) n log n

Given this, do you see how you might pick c and n<sub>0</sub>?  We're restricting n such that n ≥ 2, so it makes sense to pick n<sub>0</sub> = 2.  Similarly, since we've just proven that an log n + bn ≤ (a + b) n log n, we can pick c = a + b.

You can think of this argument as a dialog between two people:

- **Someone else**: I'm going to pick an a and b, but I won't tell you what they are.
- **You**: Um, okay.
- **Someone else**: So prove to me that there's an n<sub>0</sub> and c such that an log n + bn ≤ cn log n whenever n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>.
- **You**: Sure!  Try picking c = a + b and n<sub>0</sub> = 2.  Does that work?
- **Someone else**: Hey, you're right!  That does work!

Notice that the dialog starts with the other party choosing a and b.  That way, you can tailor your choice of c and n<sub>0</sub> to make sure the claim holds.  If you tried picking c and n<sub>0</sub> first, they could always find an a and b that would break it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Since `A` and `B` are constants, it's OK to express `C` and `N` in terms of `A` and `B`. For example, you might show that `C=A+B` and `N > 2A` are sufficient to prove that `f(n) = O(n lg n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something but this doesn't seem like typical use of Big-O. Your function is a straightforward mathematical function, not an algorithm. If:

```
f(n)=anlog(n)+bn
```

Then the complexity is the higher of that of (anlog(n)) and (bn), assuming that the plus operation has negligible complexity. Since b is constant, (bn) is O(n) and likewise as a is constant, (anlog(n)) is O(nlog(n)).